# grab file from memory process

Tags: c#, memory

Is possible in c# grab file loaded into memory by other process?
For example image file or txt file.
I've a application that load some of that file in memory. i need dump it to disk.
i suppose is hard way, can put me in correct way.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Are you looking for [`ReadProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? (you're going to have to `pinvoke` it to access it) (*edit* see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966515/c-sharp-readprocessmemory-accessing-reading-pointers)

Comment: Put that way your question is completely out of any context. Please provide more information about why you need to do that. Also explain whether the other process is a managed process or not, how is the file loaded in memory in this process, whether you have administrative privileges on the machine, ...

Comment: You can monitor files and re-read them when they accessed via that process

Answer (score 1):

This is technically not impossible.  Assuming you have sufficient rights, you can peek at the memory of another process with the ReadProcessMemory() winapi function.  Pinvoke required.

The problem you'll however run into is that you'll discover that you are trying to find a needle in a haystack.  You'll have no clue on what virtual memory to start reading unless you know a *lot* about the process.  You start off with a cool 2 billion possible choices, you can probably whittle it down to a million or so.  Throw in complications like a garbage collector that randomly moves stuff around.

Get insight in what the virtual memory of another process looks like with the SysInternals' VMMap utility.

Comment: Yes, it is a tool to get insight in how those millions of bytes are organized.

Comment: i've read some comment..if i have understand,i need to know correct base adress and offset,then i need to know size to read and grab it.or not?

Comment: Yes, that's what it takes.